# Request to un-merge Question 386376

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, reopen-request

@Synetech has pointed out that [Can't add a new search engine in Chrome](https://superuser.com/q/386376/100787) is **not** a duplicate of [Custom Chrome Search Engine for site with frames does not work](https://superuser.com/q/296328/100787). At the time of the merge, it may have been unclear what the real issue for [Custom Chrome Search Engine for site with frames does not work](https://superuser.com/q/296328/100787) was, as the user did not explicitly say their issue was with HTML frames.

So, I am requesting to reopen [Can't add a new search engine in Chrome](https://superuser.com/q/386376/100787) and move [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/386388/100787) back as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't do it by myself, [Rebecca](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140548/rebecca-chernoff) & [Nick](https://superuser.com/users/10423/nick-craver) completed the merge undo.

Comment: Perhaps we should also delete the comments on my answer, as they are no longer relevant.

Comment: @iglvzx done, nuked comments